# Excel Services delegation using Classic Mode Authentication

Tags: excel-services

Every where I'm reading about setting up Excel Services for delegation so that it can connect to Analysis Services running on separate server is based around using Claims based authentication to authenticate to the web application. However, right now we are using Classic Mode Authentication, and I can't find ANY information on how to set things up in this scenario.

Is it even possible to get this going without using Claims Authentication?

Comment: I think this may be a problem going forward as Claims becomes the preferred method to handle these distributed systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to find Microsoft's practical guide for Kerberos and service delegation: microsoft.com/downloads/… Originally published on Jul 14, 2010, with an update published today. Followed that through, and it seems that:

1. Yes, you can delegate through Excel Services, performance point, etc. while using Classic-Mode authentication
2. You still need to set up the Claims
   to Windows TokenService to be
   successful